# Unable to use Scala and Spring MVC 3 to return JSON

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc

I am converting my Java Spring controller classes to Scala.  In Java, a controller method that returned JSON was defined as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String[] searchFoods(@RequestParam("term") String searchTerm, Principal principal) { ... }
```

This works as expected.  The same method in Scala looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/search"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
def searchFoods(@RequestParam("term") searchTerm: String, principal: Principal): java.util.List[String] @ResponseBody = { ... }
```

However, any time this path is requested I get the following exception:

```
2011-10-09 09:06:19.980:WARN::/searchpath/search.html
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'searchpath/search' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
```

And the web server returns an HTTP 500 error.  Is it possible to use Scala and Spring MVC 3 together to return JSON?

Comment: We have unfiltered, blueeyes, finagle, spray, bowler, xitrium, etc... Spring is particularly hostile to Scala practices such as being type safe, favoring immutability, and not inheriting Java's collections.  Is there any compelling reason why you're obliged to work with Spring MVC instead of one of the several more appropriate native Scala frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was putting the @ResponseBody in the wrong place. It needs to appear before the method definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/search"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
@ResponseBody
def searchFoods(@RequestParam("term") searchTerm: String, principal: Principal): java.util.List[String]  = { ... }
```

I had tried this before, but forgot to clean my project. After moving the annotation to the correct location, then cleaning and rebuilding, everything was working again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue isn't JSON, but path resolution.  Try changing the method annotation to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/searchpath/search"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
```

See [this page](http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.com/2010/01/scala-spring-hibernate-maven-webapp-how.html) for a full example.

Comment: Hi Aaron, the path resolution is ok.  My controller is annotated as:     @RequestMapping(value = Array("/searchpath")) at the class level

Comment: Yup, I misread the error.  Are you using the Jackson JARs to auto-convert the objects to JSON?  Also, please post more of the stack trace.  Found a post which might be relevant: http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/spring-3-jpa-scala-jackson.  And another post: http://blog.caseylucas.com/2011/08/17/jerkson-spring-scala/